# ServiceStack.RabbitMq - how to set custom attributes on messages

Tags: rabbitmq, servicestack

We use ServiceStack.RabbitMq and I could not find a way to put a custom attribute on the rabbit mq message. I want the publisher to set the attribute on the message and the worker to read it.

A variant is to move that attribute as part of request body but I have a lot of requests and in all honesty the request should not know at all about this kind of information - as that is metadata of the message.

Any idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Message Filters in RabbitMqServer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Rabbit-MQ#message-filters) to add and introspect message properties, e.g:

```
var mqServer = new RabbitMqServer("localhost") 
{
    PublishMessageFilter = (queueName, properties, msg) => {
        properties.AppId = "app:{0}".Fmt(queueName);
    },
    GetMessageFilter = (queueName, basicMsg) => {
        var props = basicMsg.BasicProperties;
        receivedMsgType = props.Type; //automatically added by RabbitMqProducer
        receivedMsgApp = props.AppId;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either add the custom attribute to the object you are pushing down the queue or add that attribute to the rabbit message metadata header table. RabbitMQ messages have various metadata attributes that can be set when a message is published.

Check [this](https://lostechies.com/derekgreer/2012/05/29/rabbitmq-for-windows-headers-exchanges/)